# How to schedule a python script using cron job

Tags: python, cron, schedule

I am trying to schedule a python script using cron jobs via following statement in crotab :

```
00 11 * * * /usr/local/bin/python /<path to python file>
```

This script had some .to_csv statements but after 11 am when I checked the destination folder, there were no csv files. I also used `grep "file name" /var/log/cron` command to see if there was any record in the log file , didn't find any. I am using /`usr/local/bin/python` in the above command based on where python is present ( this I got by doing `which python`)

Is this the right way to schedule a python script? Please suggest if there is an alternate or a correct way. Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: What happens if you run the script directly? You can also redirect the script output into a new log file with `>> /var/log/python_job.log 2>&1`

Comment: When I run the script directly, I get the required output ( in this case generating some csv' and updating some tables).

Comment: Which user runs the cronjob? Does that user has permission to access and execute your python file?

Comment: There is really no telling without that python script, `/var/log/cron` content and information which user runs cronjobs. Also, on Debian-based systems, cron logs will actually be in `/var/log/syslog`. You can modify your script to provide more debugging info and [configure your system to place all output where you can find it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29759/65754).